# How to use pip freeze to get the full version of a package including the post-release version?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pyspark

It seems that `pip freeze` command does not include the post-release version of the packages.

For example, when I install `pyspark` using `pip install pyspark` command, it works well and then `pip freeze` command shows `pyspark==2.2.0`. However, It's incorrect because when I uninstall `pyspark` and then try to install it using `pip install pyspark==2.2.0` command, I get the following error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyspark==2.2.0 (from versions: 2.2.0.post0)
No matching distribution found for pyspark==2.2.0
```

So the available version is `2.2.0.post0`, but `pip freeze` does not include the post-release version. It's kind of annoying because every time I save the list of project packages in `requirements.txt` file using `pip freeze > requirements.txt` command, I need to modify the version of `pyspark` manually.